# The total variation of functions in the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

This question has already been addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118958/total-variation-of-weakly-differentiable-functions) and there's also a proof in [Wikkipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#equation_6) but to my frustration, I can't find any of these proofs to be coherent :| So I decided to come up with my own proof, albeit I admit I borrowed some ideas from here and there :) If you have the time, I'd be grateful if you checked my solution (particularly the bolded line) to see if it hits the nail on the head.

preliminary information:

> **Lemma 1.**
>   If 
>   $f_n \rightarrow f$
>   in
>   $L^1$
>   then there exists a subsequence
>   $f_{n_j}$
>   such that a.e
>   $f_{n_j}\rightarrow f$.
>
> **Lemma 2 [The Dominated Convergence Theorem].**
>   If
>   $f_n$
>   is a sequence of integrable functions such that firstly,
>   $f_n \rightarrow f$
>   a.e and secondly, there exists a function
>   $g\in L^1$
>   such that a.e
>   $\lvert f_n \rvert \leq g$
>   then
>   $\int f = \lim_n \int f_n$.
>
> (Both lemmas are proved in *Folland's Real Analysis* book.)

**Problem.** Define
 $$TV(u,\Omega):=\sup\left\{\int_\Omega u(x) \operatorname{div} \phi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \colon \phi\in  C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n),\ \Vert \phi\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\le 1\right\}$$
If
$u\in W^{1,1}$
 then
$TV(u,\Omega) = \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u(x) \rvert \, dx$.

> **Solution.**
>   By performing $n$ simple integrations by parts and summing up the results we easily see that
>   $\int\limits_\Omega u\operatorname{div}\varphi = -\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\varphi$
>   therefore
>   $$\int\limits_\Omega u\operatorname{div} \mathbf\phi = - \int\limits_\Omega \mathbf\phi\cdot\nabla u \leq \left| \int\limits_\Omega \mathbf\phi\cdot\nabla u \right|\leq \int\limits_\Omega \left|\mathbf\phi\right|\cdot\left|\nabla u\right|\leq \int\limits_\Omega \left|\nabla u\right|.$$
>   So in order to show that the supremum over $\phi$ of the leftmost term equals the rightmost term, it suffices to find a sequence
>   $(\phi_n)_1^{\infty}$
>   such that
>    $\int\limits_\Omega u\operatorname{div} \mathbf\phi_n$
>   tends to
>    $\int\limits_\Omega \left|\nabla u\right| $.
>
> Assume that
>    $\nabla u \neq 0$
>    (otherwise the result follows trivially).
>     Since
>      $u\in W^{1,1}$
>       we have 
>    $ \nabla u \in L^1$ thus $\frac{-\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u \rvert} \in L^1$
>    and since
>    $C_c^1$
>    is dense in
>    $L^1$
>    there is a sequence 
>    $(\phi_n)_1^{\infty} \subset C_c^1$
>    such that
>    $\phi_n \rightarrow \frac{-\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u \rvert}$
>    in
>    $L^1$, and **since the limit function $\frac{-\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u \rvert}$ is a unit vector (function), we may assume $\phi_n$'s are unit vectors so that thay have norm 1.**
>
> By the first lemma above, there is a subsequence
>     $(\phi_{n_j})$
>   such that a.e 
>   $ \phi_{n_j} \rightarrow  \frac{-\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u \rvert}$
>   thus 
>   $$ \nabla u \cdot \phi_{n_j} \rightarrow  \frac{-\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u  \rvert  }\cdot \nabla u \quad \text{a.e}.$$
>   Furthermore
>   $$ \lvert \phi_{n_j}.\nabla u  \rvert \leq \lvert 
> \phi_{n_j} \rvert \lvert \nabla  u \rvert \leq   \lvert \nabla u \rvert \in L^1. $$
>   Henece both conditions of the second Lemma are met and this Lemma guarantees that we are eligible to take the $lim$ inside the integral:
>   $$ \lim_j \int\limits_\Omega u\operatorname{div} \mathbf\phi_{n_j} = -\lim_j \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \phi_{n_j} = -\int_{\Omega} \lim_j \nabla u \cdot \phi_{n_j} = \int  \frac{\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u  \rvert  }\cdot \nabla u = \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u \rvert. \quad \square $$

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that $\nabla u\ne0$ everywhere in $\Omega$. It could be that $\nabla u=0$ on a set $E$ of positive measure and $\nabla u\ne0$ in $\Omega\setminus E$.

**Update**
Assume that $\Omega$ is bounded. Define 
$$g(x):=\begin{cases}-\frac{\nabla u(x)}{\lvert \nabla u(x) \rvert}&\text{if } \nabla u(x)\ne 0,\\0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then $g\in L^1(\Omega)$ and so you can find $(\phi_n)_1^{\infty} \subset C_c^1$ converging to $g$ in $L^1$. 
Consider a smooth function $F:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $F(y)=y$ if $|y|\le 2$ and $F(y)=0$ if $|y|\ge 4$ and take $g_{n_j}(x):=F(\phi_{n_j}(x))$. Then $|g_{n_j}(x)|\le 4$ and $g_{n_j}(x)\to g(x)$ since if $\phi_{n_j}(x)\to g(x)$, then $|\phi_{n_j}(x)|\le 2$ for all $j$ large enough, since $|g(x)|\le 1$. You can now continue as in your proof.

Comment: I assumed $\nabla u \neq  0 $ so as to prevent the denominator of $\frac{\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u \rvert}$ from vanishing. If I assume the gradient vanishes on set $ٍE$ of positive measure, does it affect the proof? Also, do you have any comments about the rest of the proof? Anything else wrong? Am I allowed to assume the $\phi_n$'s are unit vectors?

Comment: I added more details to my reply. You don't need unit vectors, just bounded.